# After saved the data,data must be stable and non-deletable by clicking delete button in a grid.Can anyone suggest?

Tags: acumatica

After saving the data, data must be stable and non-deletable by clicking the delete button in a grid. Can anyone suggest??

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. Are you asking how to prevent a user from deleting values from a grid?

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion is to invest some of your time and go through Acumatica Developer Trainings (T100 - T300) on [Acumatica Open University](https://openuni.acumatica.com/)